# Simulink accelerator mode. Mex error

Tags: windows, matlab, simulink, mex

I am trying to run a Simulink model in 'accelerator' mode. 
When I start the simulation it starts compiling things the I get this error:

> ### Compiling xxxxxxxxxx_acc.c
>       C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2011a\bin\mex -c  -win32  OPTIMFLAGS="/Od /Oy- /DNDEBUG"  -f C:\Users\Gui\AppData\Roaming\MATHWO~1\MATLAB\R2011a\mexopts.bat  xxxxxxxxxx_acc.c
>   'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
>   operable program or batch file.
>   NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'C:\Program' : return code '0x1'
>   Stop.

Seems the space in 'Program files' is the culprit.

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: Did you run, `mex -setup`?  Seems like I've run into this before.  Sounds like `mex` is using the wrong compiler.  Do you have xPC installed?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the path in quotes:

```
"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2011a\bin\mex" -c  -win32  OPTIMFLAGS="/Od /Oy- /DNDEBUG"  -f C:\Users\Gui\AppData\Roaming\MATHWO~1\MATLAB\R2011a\mexopts.bat  xxxxxxxxxx_acc.c
```

Comment: Yes thank you but that path is generated by Simulink , I dont know how to tell it to add quotes or use mex directly (it's in my path)